# Meaning of the verb "tap" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

That is from this [article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/fulfillment-any-age/201905/new-way-looking-the-personality-the-bragger).

> The overclaiming measure, that assessment of bragging which **taps** saying you know about something that you don’t, was tested with questionnaires that gave them items from popular culture that have never happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like the writer is using this verb "taps" in a colloquial way that is probably *close* to a dictionary definition but not quite.

I would say that the closest dictionary definition is to *draw from*, but I feel like it could also be an abbreviation of the phrase *to tap into*, which means to access a resource with the purpose of drawing from it.

> The overclaiming measure, that assessment of bragging which taps saying you know about something that you don’t, was tested with questionnaires that gave them items from popular culture that have never happened.

"Overclaiming" is something referred to in the preceding paragraphs and is a particular *type* of bragging. The "*overclaiming measure*" therefore is a way of *assessing* or *measuring* that behaviour from a psychology point of view. When it goes on to say "*that assessment of bragging which taps you know about something that you don’t*" it is an *explanation* of what the writer means by "the overclaiming measure". I feel that, as the article strongly suggests bragging in its many forms is a *compulsion* for some types of people, it is like a resource that a person "*taps into*". So "overclaiming" *taps* (or draws from) the bragger's desire to claim to know more about something than they actually do.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is very badly written, as is the rest of the article. I don't think "taps" is used correctly here in any sense. The clause "saying you know about something that you don't" seems to be a definition of "overclaiming" (even though "overclaiming" was already defined earlier in the article). After reading the whole article to understand the context, I think the author means:

> The participants were given questionnaires to test for overclaiming, which is a form of bragging where one claims to know something they don't. The questionnaires contained made-up facts about pop culture.

Again, I find the entire article to be very poorly written, and you should probably disregard it as a source for learning English.

Answer (score 1):

There are three means of the verb tap:

a) Hit one thing lightly against another:

John tapped his fingers against the table in annoyance.

b) Draw a supply from a source (commonly the supply is a liquid but can also be used in other contexts):

John read a book by Alan Turing, hoping to tap into the authors knowledge on code breaking.

This second meaning is also why you might tap a phone or a keg, i.e. to draw the information from the phone conversation, or to draw the beer from a keg.

I agree with TypeIA's interpretation of the paragraph though.

Comment: Do you think any of these definitions (you only gave two, by the way) fit the sentence given?

Comment: Oh sorry yes I did only give two, I was going to split up knowledge and liquid but then I decided they actually could share the same definition! I am unsure which the author is trying to use if I'm honest.

He could mean that the statement which is over claiming is tapping into the resource of a subject the participant knows nothing about.

However, he could also means touches gently upon the knowledge beyond the participants reach.

Comment: OK, I'm with you. There are at least three more meanings though: to tap 
dance; to avoid, as in "tap around [a subject]," a metaphor from tap dancing; and to cut a threaded hole in an object, as for a screw. But I think it's clear the author did not mean any of those things!

Comment: Tap dance is actually the same as option (a), the name is from the way your toes/heels lightly tap the floor. The other two you have given are consequences of both these definitions I believe. I haven't heard the phrase tap around but cut a threaded hole in an object comes originally from  the need to draw something from that object (i.e. to tap a keg).